# What's wrong with this html page?

Tags: html, curl, special-characters, response, wget

Which I'd like to convert specific page to the text file or use wget (e.g. `-m`) to download some links which are on it, however most of the tools are failing to interpret the source.

For example:

```
$ curl http://www.free-energy-info.co.uk/ | html2text
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 2896)
```

However using `-check` returns the source code correctly:

```
$ html2text -check http://www.free-energy-info.co.uk/
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>
...
```

Then I've found that this page consist some binary data and special characters, e.g.:

```
$ curl -s http://www.free-energy-info.co.uk/ | head | cat -v
M-^?M-~<^@h^@t^@m^@l^@>^@
^@
^@<^@h^@e^@a^@d^@>^@
^@
^@<^@T^@I^@T^@L^@E^@>^@F^@r^@e^@e^@-^@E^@n^@e^@r^@g^@y^@ ^@D^@e^@v^@i^@c^@e^@s^@,^@ ^@z^@e^@r^@o^@-^@p^@o^@i^@n^@t^@ ^@e^@n^@e^@r^@g^@y^@,^@ ^@a^@n^@d^@ ^@w^@a^@t^@e^@r^@ ^@a^@s^@ ^@H^@H^@O^@ ^@f^@u^@e^@l^@<^@/^@T^@I^@T^@L^@E^@>^@
```

What's wrong with this website? Is it a bug of the web server, source code has been scrambled deliberately or it's using some special format (since it doesn't look compressed)? How to make this page understandable for the standard utils (such as `wget`)?

Note that it works perfectly fine in the web browser.

Comment: Getting the same result with curl, also when sending a valid user agent. However, wget works for me.

Comment: @Paul Wget downloads a single page, but it isn't following any links (when specifying `-m` or `-r`), like it doesn't understand the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page is simply in `UTF-16LE` format (this can be checked by [W3 Validator](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.free-energy-info.co.uk%2F&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)).

The initial binary sequence (`U+FEFF` for UTF-16BE, `U+FFFE` for UTF-16LE) is called [the byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM) which signalling to a program that the text is Unicode encoded (either 8-bit, 16-bit or 32-bit).

```
$ curl -s http://www.free-energy-info.co.uk/ | hexdump -n2
0000000 ff fe
```

So it sounds like `wget` or `html2text` doesn't support such format yet. It downloads, but the issue is with content parsing (recursive downloads). Current version of wget assumes that input data is usable with traditional C string functions, but UTF-16 (Unicode) can't be used with it (see: [The input byte stream](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#the-input-byte-stream)).

---

As for workaround you can convert the source code back to `UTF-8` by using `iconv` command, e.g.

```
$ curl -s http://www.free-energy-info.co.uk/ | iconv -f "UTF-16" -t "UTF-8" | head | cat -v
<html>
<head>
<TITLE>Free-Energy Devices, zero-point energy, and water as HHO fuel</TITLE>
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="magnet power, free energy devices, power from aerials, gravity power, water power, renewable energy and electronics tutorial.">
```

So the syntax to save page with `curl` into UTF-8, could be:

```
curl -s http://example.com/ | iconv -f "UTF-16" -t "UTF-8" > index.html
```

Then to make `html2text` to work, read the source code from the standard input, e.g.

```
iconv -f "UTF-16" -t "UTF-8" <(curl -s http://www.free-energy-info.co.uk/) | html2text
```

And for wget you can specify `--remote-encoding`, but this is not supported yet and it fails with:

> This version does not have support for IRIs

<sup>Tested in GNU Wget 1.16.3.</sup>

---

I've reported this bug at [#47689](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?47689), where [*Tim Ruehsen*](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?47689#comment3) stated that he committed the support parsing of UTF-16 encoded HTML pages to the next version 2 of wget, but it still needs some work (e.g. `-k` still doesn't work).

After testing a new version, try:

```
wget -r --local-encoding=UTF-16LE --input-file index.html --force-html --base http://www.free-energy-info.co.uk
```

as suggested by [Tim](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?47689#comment2).

<sup>Note: Add `-d` if your wget was compiled with debugging support.</sup>